# Добавление информации в одну таблицу из нескольких по нажатию кнопки

Tags: access, delphi, sql

Привет. У нас имеется несколько таблиц (http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_7719688_12088891.png).Нам необходимо из таблиц ZakazIzMenu, Ingridienty и SostavBluda  в таблицу Zatraty вставить поля Ingridienty.ID_I, SostavBluda.KolichestvoIngridienta*ZakazIzMenu.Kolichestvo и текущую дату или дату из таблицы ZakazIzMenu. Пробовали осуществить следующим образом, но выводило только 1 строку со значениями '1' в первых двух столбцах.

```
Form11.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Insert;
Form11.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_IZ').Value:=Form8.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_I').AsString;
Form11.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('KolZatr').Value:=ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select SostavBluda.KolichestvoIngridienta*ZakazIzMenu.Kolichestvo from SostavBluda, ZakazIzMenu, Bluda where ZakazIzMenu.ID_B=Bluda.ID_B and Bluda.ID_B=SostavBluda.NameBluda');
Form11.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('DataZ').AsDateTime:=Date;
Form11.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Post;
```

Данная таблица необходима в дальнейшем для обработки и выявления статистики. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Группировку нигде не забыли?

Comment: ну условие у нас ZakazIzMenu.ID_B=Bluda.ID_B, то есть оно совпадает с объединением таблиц.
Группировку добавили Group By ID_I

Comment: Который из заказов вы смотрите, вот в чем вопрос. Может я что-то не понимаю - я на схему данных не смотрел.

А по поводу остального - вы добавляете в грид одну запись, поставляете идентификатор из формы 8, а в качестве количества берете количество первого попавшегося ингредиента из произвольного блюда заказа.